# How to perform Parameter Propagation for Parameter Variation experiment in Anylogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to set up an parameter variation experiment in Anylogic for an agent based model. In main agent there are two population of agents with their own parameters inside their diagram. I have read the anylogic help that the experiment requires "Parameter Propagation" but the problem is I cannot understand it clearly to how to apply it. Does it mean that we need the same parameters to be made again in main agent and linked to the ones inside the other agents? for example in `economy` agent there is a parameter called the `InflationRate` and I want to propagate it in main so I can run the experiment. If you show me how to do it with an example I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a parameter on Main like `myMainParam`. This one can be varied by the ParamVar experiment.

Now in your population, you add a parameter and name it any way you like, say `myAgentParam`. Next, you select the agent population on Main. It its properties, you will see `myAgentParam` shown with a code box next to it. Here, you specify `myMainParam` so that it's value will be pulled from it.

Done.